# How to structure git with django apps/templates

Tags: django, git, github

I just did the django tutorial and I'm trying to develop an app with a friend. Currently the web application consists of an app and a template directories. The tutorial implies that templates and apps are to be kept in separate folders, yet a change in one is likely to cause a change in the other.

How are an app's templates usually shipped and stored? Do I really need two separate repositories for this one project? Is there a document or guide somewhere that is that canonical text for these kinds of django questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I wouldn't say splitting templates into a different repository sounds like a good idea. Where does it imply putting into separate repositories? Does it even mention VCS?

The standard practice is to put app specific templates in a `templates` directory inside of the app which will be discovered by django's default [`app_directories` template loader.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)

`myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/templates_here`

For global site wide templates (such as the base template), it makes sense to put them in a directory you define in [`settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs)

Comment: I knew that it had to be something really obvious like that! Thank you it worked like a charm! Do you know of any good resources for questions about django project structuring?

Comment: @Sandro I actually don't know of any references -- I've developed my own over the years based on what I see / what worked. For me my primary concern is keeping my files and folders as focused as possible. Just moving my apps away from the root directory helps clarify the root directory itself (not having urls, settings, app1, utils, templates, static, etc. all in one place)... moving settings and related configs into a settings folder has been extremely useful too.